# How to get the reason why threads are sleeping

Tags: linux, multithreading

In linux,is there any method to know why a thread is sleeping? Maybe a thread calls sleep voluntarily,  maybe a thread is waiting for some I/O operations or just a irq occurs?

Comment: Load your program up in a debugger (gdb) and get a backtrace of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strace <command>`. You may have to install the *strace* package first.